# Find number of breaks in a sequence

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a program that is parsing allele sequences. I am trying to write a code that determines if the allele is complete or not. To do so, I need to count the number of breaks in the reference sequence. A break is signified by a string of '-'. If there is more than one break I want the program to say "Incomplete Allele."

How can I figure out how to count the number of breaks in the sequence?

Here is an example of a "broken" sequence:

```
>DQB1*04:02:01
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
--ATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGAT-------CCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACT
GTGACCTT----GATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCC
CGAGGATTTCGTGTTCCAGTTTAAGGGCATGTGCTACTTCACCAACGGGACCGAGCGCGT
GCGGGGTGTGACCAGATACATCTATAACCGAGAGGAGTACGCGCGCTTCGACAGCGACGT
GGGGGTGTATCGGGCGGTGACGCCGCTGGGGCGGCTTGACGCCGAGTACTGGAATAGCCA
GAAGGACATCCTGGAGGAGGACCGGGCGTCGGTGGACACCGTATGCAGACACAACTACCA
GTTGGAGCTCCGCACGACCTTGCAGCGGCGA-----------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
---GTGGAGCCCACAGTGACCATCTCCCCATCCAGGACAGAGGCCCTCAACCACCACAAC
CTGCTGGTCTGCTCAGTGACAGATTTCTATCCAGCCCAGATCAAAGTCCGGTGGTTTCGG
AATGACCAGGAGGAGACAACTGGCGTTGTGTCCACCCCCCTTATTAGGAACGGTGACTGG
ACCTTCCAGATCCTGGTGATGCTGGAAATGACTCCCCAGCGTGGAGACGTCTACACCTGC
CACGTGGAGCACCCCAGCCTCCAGAACCCCATCATCGTGGAGTGGCGGGCTCAGTCTGAA
TCTGCCCAGAGCAAGATGCTGAGTGG----CATTGGAGGCTTCGTGCTGGGGCTGATCTT
CCTCGGGCTGGGCCTTATTATC--------------CATCACAGGAGTCAGAAAGGGCTC
CTGCACTGA---------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
idx=[]
for m in range(len(sequence)):
    for n in re.finditer('-',sequence[0]): 
        idx.append(n.start())
counter=0
min_val=[]
for n in range(len(idx)):
    if counter==idx[n]:
        counter=counter+1
    elif counter !=0:
        min_val.append(idx[n-1])
        counter=0
```

My reasoning for the above code was if I could find the start positions of the '-' then I can see how many times they appear within the sequence and if they break the sequence at all. However, I know there are some flaws in the above code.

Comment: What defines "a sequence"? How many sequences and how many breaks are in your example?

Comment: You do not use `m` in your loop but just test `sequence[0]` for `m` iterations; did you mean `sequence[m]`? Also, I assume `idx[n[` should be `idx[n]`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist The above example is one sequence and there are five breaks. The part of my program that i did not show basically reads files and assigns them into a sequence array. I only am looking for breaks within the first sequence which is the reference sequence or ">DQB1*04:02:01". Since I am only looking at the first sequence this is why I am testing sequence[0] for m iterations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can just count the occurrances of `-+`, i.e. a sequence of *one or more* `-` symbols. The only problem are the line breaks, but you could either incorporate those into the regex, or split and join the string before matching.

```
>>> sequence = """>DQB1*04:02:01....."""
>>> joined = ''.join(sequence.splitlines())
>>> sum(1 for m in re.finditer("-+", joined))
7
```

Note: This includes the `-` at the start and end of the sequence.

Or reverse the approach: Instead of counting the gaps, count the groups:

```
>>> sum(1 for m in re.finditer("[GATC]+", joined))
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just filter out all the '-' characters and based on the number of remaining segments determine number of breaks.

```
str_list = filter(None, sequence.split('-'))
if len(str_list) > 2:
    return "Incomplete Allele"
else:
    return "Complete Allele"
```

Comment: Only problem you may have with this is if you care about leading ----'s or trailing ---'s

Comment: You also have to get rid of the header and the line breaks.

Comment: I could not tell from the question if that is a problem OP could respond and I would more than happy adjust things for the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do:

```
def test(sequence):
    sequence = ''.join(sequence.splitlines()[1:]) # remove first line (header and line breaks)
    S = [segments for segments in sequence.split('-') if block != '']
    if len(S)>2: # len(S) should be the number of remaining segments
        print "Incomplete Allele."
```

Comment: Really? what `len(S)` do you get?

Comment: This works for me with `sequence = s = '--ATAG--TCG--GAT---CCTT--GG--TAGCAACT' for example. Can you give the exact string to test on, does it include new line characters?